# SQL Server > How to query a sum from logs

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table below contains state changes of three users over time.
I am trying to make a query that return **the sum of the state of all users, but only from today most recent row**.

`idEvent | date   |    user     | state 

5             | 05/22  |   client1 | 0       <- This number

4             | 05/22  |   client2 | 1       <- Plus this number

3            | 05/12  |   client1 | 0

2            | 05/12  |   client2 | 0

1            | 05/02  |   client3 | 1`


With this data the sum of today most recent state from clients is 1 (client1 most recent state = 0 and client2 most recent state = 1).

So far i've come with 

`SELECT sum(a.states) FROM 

(SELECT sum(state) AS states 

FROM TABLE 

WHERE day(date) = day(getdate()) AND month(date) = month(getdate()) AND year(date) = year(getdate())

group by user) a` 
but it sums every state of the day, not the most recent...

Can anyone help me ?
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `row_number()` to find the most recent rows, as in:

```
select sum(t.states)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [user] order by [date] desc, idevent desc) as seqnum
      from [table] t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This doesn't guarantee that they are from today.  For that, a `where` clause is needed:

```
select sum(t.states)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [user] order by [date] desc, idevent desc) as seqnum
      from [table] t
      where [date] >= cast(getdate() as date) and [date] < cast(getdate() + 1 as date)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `where` clause does not use any functions on the date column so appropriate indexes can be used (if available).

Comment: `user` must be in square brackets, otherwise the answer is wrong

Comment: @Aryadev . . . Yes (or double quotes).  No accounting for bad column names.  (Did you notice that the query in the question won't work for the same reason?)

Comment: yeah, it's interesting. It's the first time I see how poor column naming results in wrong query results :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ROWNUMBER and PARTITION BY...

SELECT sum(STATE) FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [USER] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS ROWNUMBER 
FROM #TEMP
) T
WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1